# Position an image randomly on a view in swiftui and pass the position of the image to another fullscreen transparent view

Tags: swiftui

I have a view in `SwiftUI`. This view has some random images on it in various random positions. Check the code below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .position( 
                        x: CGFloat.random(in: 0..<screenWidth),
                        y:  CGFloat.random(in: 0..<screenHeight)
                    )
            }
        }
        .ignoreSafeArea()
    }
}
```

I need to get the exact position of these random added images and pass the positions to another transparent view that shows up with a `ZStack` on top of the previous view. In the transparent popup fullscreen `ZStack` view i need to point to the position of the images i randomly put in the previous view using arrow images. Is this somehow possible in swiftui? I am new in swiftui so any help or suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the random offsets in a `@State var` and generate them in `.onAppear { }`.  Then you can use them to position the random images and pass the offsets to the overlay view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var imageOffsets: [CGPoint] = Array(repeating: CGPoint.zero, count: 5)
    @State private var showingOverlay = true
    
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .position(
                        x: imageOffsets[index].x,
                        y: imageOffsets[index].y
                    )
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onAppear {
            for index in 0..<5 {
                imageOffsets[index] = CGPoint(x: .random(in: 0..<screenWidth), y: .random(in: 0..<screenHeight))
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            if showingOverlay {
                OverlayView(imageOffsets: imageOffsets)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct OverlayView: View {
    let imageOffsets: [CGPoint]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                Circle()
                    .stroke(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .position(
                        x: imageOffsets[index].x,
                        y: imageOffsets[index].y
                    )
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```